# What is it about COBOL and its performance that makes it (compared to its age) so quick?

Tags: compiler-construction, cobol

Reading through some of the questions here, the general concensus seems to be that there to continues to be an enourmous amount of COBOL code "out there", not just because it's a nightmare to refactor or re-code, but simply because for a certain market segment (financials etc.), it has proven itself to be more than capable of holding its own. But what **is** it about the language that causes it to be so? How can something that is several decades old continue to perform well enough to hold its own against more modern languages, with all the comensurate improvements in memory management etc.? Have the COBOL compilers etc. simply improved silently in the background? Or is there something inherent in the language that means it is extremely efficient for a given set of operations?

Comment: Should maybe a community wiki than a question.

Comment: I'm not looking for opinions: I'd really like to know what the technical reason is. Compilers, memory, whatever.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The COBOL language was designed in the 1950s to match the capabilities of the slow, RAM-limited machines available at the time. Not to mention the lack of interactive terminals. Many aspects of the design are made to be easy to compile into straightforward machine code with no optimization needed. For instance, there are no variables. Only a single block of working storage, with names that refer to byte arrays of a specific fixed length starting at a fixed location. COBOL programs compile to efficient machine code by design.

As CPUs got faster and RAM got more plentiful, COBOL compilers did add new features like key-indexed file I/O and built-in MERGE algorithm, and support for interactive text terminals. Noawadays there is even object-oriented COBOL.

So part of the reason is that the code was portable to new CPU architectures since it was a high-level language, yet very efficient since it was designed to not use fancy features like those found in ALGOL-60, an ancestor of C. And part of the reason is that COBOL evolved to fit into newer OSes and capabilities. For instance, SQL databases are just more sophisticated forms of the simple table-oriented files that COBOL was designed to handle. Overlay linkers allowed huge COBOL programs to be written as long as the execution flow was roughly sequential. Any feature that was better done in Assembler or PL/1 or FORTRAN, could be accessed via PROCEDURE calls.

The closest modern language to COBOL is Python, because you can write clean programs that almost read like English without extraneous punctuation everywhere, but you can leverage a large and sophisticated library of features rather than having to code your own all the time. Of course Python has adopted all of the features of ALGOL-60 and more, because it was designed in the modern era when you don't have to fit everything into 16k of RAM.

Comment: "Large and sophisticated library of features" -- lots of built in keywords for various things -- but alas no libraries whatsoever. You end up coding simple date calculations, re-formatting strings etc. by hand over and over again.

Comment: Hmmm... modern programmers use Google to apply the DRY principle.  https://pypi.python.org/pypi/iso8601  https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-datetime-tz/0.2  https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-chrono/0.3.0 and there are lots more. Or if you cannot use these, then at least write your own library.

Answer (score 6):

On OS/360 and its descendents there was about a ratio of four assembly instructions to a COBOL verb, the hardware designers had a good look at the COBOL spec and built an instruction set to support it.

Even seemingly monstrous statemens like :-

```
PERFORM BEGIN-PARA THROUGH END-PARA VARYING I FROM 1 BY 2 TO MAX_ARRAY.
```

Transalates to about eight assembly instructions (only 1 of which is inside the loop)

Answer (score 5):

It's because COBOL programs (at least the old ones) are very simply structured, so it's not at all difficult to compile them to efficient machine code. For example, "good-old" cobol programs have no need for efficient memory management, because dynamic allocation of memory simply doesn't happen; the memory layout is fixed at compile time.

Comment: +1, plus it's also a language pretty much designed for batch type business operations, which maps well to the uses it's put to in the financial world

Answer (score 4):

Another point if favour or COBOL in a financial setting is that it provies native data types and mathematical operators for doing decimal fixed point arithemetic (see: [Packed Decimal][1]).

Packed Decimal is useful for doing financial computations because it maintains a fixed number of digits before and after the decimal point. This makes it a little easier to deal with rounding of financial amounts.

Few languages other than COBOL, PL/1 and Algol can efficiently do arithmetic in decimal fixed point. IBM mainframe computers have dedicated hardware circuts for doing calculations in BCD which helps keep COBOL performance somewhere up in the stratosphere.

[1]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packed_decimal"Packed Decimal"

Comment: There are quite a few languages that have decimal fixed point as a distinct type (VB had `Currency`, for example, and it was also available to any COM-enabled language). The trick is having hardware that works well with that.

Answer (score 2):

The quiet advantage COBOL has long held is that the language itself separates data from instructions.  Data is held in the DATA DIVISION, while the code is kept at arm's length in the PROCEDURE DIVISION.  This helps encourage writing "stateless" procedures, which is a critical aspect of writing modular, easily testable code.  COBOL was ahead of the Object Oriented people in this regard, a lesson many C++ and Java folks seem to have forgotten 15 years ago.

Of course you can violate the principle, but as it's just as easy to write the code well, most seasoned COBOL developers do.

That's part of the reason COBOL is still in surprisingly widespread use.  Because it's modular, it's more reusable, so people continue to reuse it.  And why not?  It's paid for.